# "What just happened?" vs "What did just happen?"

Tags: auxiliary-verbs

I've always used "What did just happen?" because I believe we are asking about the object of the verb "happen" so I use an auxiliary and the infinitive.
However, I've heard native speakers say "What just happened?", is this correct too?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> What did just happen?

– is not a correct neutral way of forming this question. ‘What’ here is not the object of ‘happen’, but the subject: *It* happened => *What* happened? ‘Happen’ is an intransitive verb and cannot take an object (“†It happened an earthquake” is grammatically incorrect).

You *can*, however, say “What did just happen?” as an emphatic question:

> — Woah, what just happened?
>   — Yeah, what *did* just happen?

This is a different use of ‘do’, of course, where the main verb is emphasised. It differs from the purely automatic ‘do’ that appears in subject-auxiliary inversion. Similarly, you could also say, “Who *did* do that?” as an emphatic variant of “Who did that?”.

Comment: Is there any context where you can use "yeah, what *did* just happen?" other than as an immediate response to "what just happened?"  I can't think of one.

Comment: Perhaps not with the ‘yeah’, but as a general emphatic, “What _did_ just happen?” works fine for me on, say, hearing a loud bang from next door. If you remove ‘just’, it becomes even easier to find appropriate contexts: “I tell you, that never happened!” — “Okay, so what did happen, then?”